# My Rspec won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

This is the error that I am getting while trying to do bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:

```
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
/Users/hetzerbr/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require': /Users/hetzerbr/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
    config.fixture_path => "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
                          ^
    from /Users/hetzerbr/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `autorun'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
```

I'm using Mac Osx10.8 with brew install and RVM and ruby 1.8.7. I am in the middle of chapter five of the ruby on rails tutorial 
FIXED BY COMMENT BELOW however, now I am getting this error:

```
rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:177:in `require': no such file to load -- iconv (LoadError)
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:177
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:3:in `require'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:3
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:2
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/sample_app/config/application.rb:13
    from /Users/hetzerbr/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2
    from /Users/hetzerbr/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:10:in `require'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:10
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/spork-0.9.0/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:4
    from /Users/hetzerbr/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `autorun'
    from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using rocket notation to assign value, you should be using `=` (equals) sign.  In you `spec/spec_helper.rb`, find the line `config.fixture_path` and modify as follows:

```
config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
```

And try running your tests again.

Comment: That worked, thank you!The test still does not run though for some reason? I get the second error listed above

Comment: do you have the `iconv` gem installed and properly required? It seems to be choking on iconv

Comment: I don't think I do actually...do you know the gemfile for ruby 1.8.7 using homebrew and rvm on a mac osx10.8?

Comment: @user2524749, try installing `libiconv` using `sudo brew install libiconv`

Comment: I already installed libiconv, but just a side question, isn't sudo only used for linux?

Comment: @user2524749, on any Unix-like systems.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo
Did you solve your issue?

Comment: Ohhh interesting...
no, I have libiconv installed via brew install libiconv and I just updated my Xcode to 4.6.3 but I still get the error

Comment: This is just a guess because I was reading this https://gist.github.com/MeetDom/1713910.  So you could try running the `sudo brew link libiconv` to make sure the the `libiconv` is linked to `/usr/local`.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions, but I already have the libiconv linked to /usr/local. Also I can't do sudo brew link libiconv because You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root. However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so for the mac you can just do brew link libiconv

Comment: Figured it out! I had to change my routes file to:
match '/static_pages/home', :to =>'static_pages#home'

Comment: Hi Bhetzie I'm having the same problem... where did you make the change on what file/directory?